# C# Custom dll - ActiveX component can't create object error in Microsoft Access

Tags: c#, vba, ms-access-2010, com-interop, epplus

I have created a c# dll that I use in COM.
It also makes use of the EPPlus.dll
VBA in MS Access picks up the object, but i get an error "ActiveX component can't create object"

I've posted my code for C# and VBA below. I use 32 bit MS Office, compile the dlls to 32bit and use 32bit regasm.

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ExcelFormula
{
    [Guid("A0F2FFB6-E4B1-4AE2-BEB2-4A313E6B9F4D")]
    public interface IEvaluator
    { 
        object Formula(string formula);
    }

    [Guid("3A0EC860-6EE8-4351-8602-D23DB3FF1A10")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ProgId("ExcelFormula.Evaluator")]
    public class Evaluator : IEvaluator
    { 
        ExcelWorksheet ws;
        private ExcelPackage excelPackage;

        public ExcelWorksheet WorkSheet
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.excelPackage == null)
                {
                excelPackage = new ExcelPackage();
                }

                if (ws == null)
                {
                    ws = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("NoName_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMMdd_hh_mm_ss"));
                }

                return ws;
            }
        }

        ~Evaluator()
        {
            if (excelPackage != null)
            {
                excelPackage.Workbook.Dispose();
                excelPackage.Dispose();
            }
        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        public object Formula(string formula)
        {
            try
            {
              WorkSheet.Cells[1, 1].Formula = formula;
              WorkSheet.Cells[1, 1].Calculate();
              return ws.Cells[1, 1].Value;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

[image: VBA Code and Error]

**EDIT**

Silly me.. I see part of the problem already.

**EDIT 2**
Problem still exists. I dont understand how it runs fine in the console app but not from VBA

Comment: You'll need to expose the interface as well. Simply decorate it with a `[ComVisible(true)]` attribute and re-register your DLL.

Comment: So a few things also needs to be taken into consideration:
1)  Find out what version of office, if 32bit then use 32 bit RegAsm and compile 32bit dll  2) Comments are required else the functions wont appear in the err.. classviewer  3) Comvisible(true) is required for all methods you want to expose. 4) An interface is NOT required, 5) A Guid above the class helps. 6) In assembly info enable COM as well as in Properties->Build->Register for COM interop

Comment: I am having the exact same situation via MS Access with the exact same error in trying to register my C# Library. Did you ever figure out what the issue was?